# yandex карта - смена метки на телефонах

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Есть вот такой код yandex карты с меткой. но по задачи нужно немного изменить center на телефонах, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей? подскажите пожалуйста

````
    ymaps.ready(function () {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [<?=($map[0]+0.0001)?>, <?=($map[1]+0.004)?>],
            zoom: 17
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
            myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([<?=$map[0]?>, <?=$map[1]?>], {
                hintContent: '<?=$arResult['NAME']?>',
                balloonContent: '<?=$arResult['NAME']?><br><?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['ADRESS']['VALUE']?>'
            }, {
                // Опции.
                // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
                iconLayout: 'default#image',
                // Своё изображение иконки метки.
                iconImageHref: '/local/templates/main/images/map-i.png',
                // Размеры метки.
                iconImageSize: [35, 47],
                // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
                // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
                iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
            });
        myMap.geoObjects
            .add(myPlacemark)
    });
} ```
````

Comment: может какой-то медиа запрос кидать, только куда?